# How to Set up Google Analytics Site Search

Tags: google-analytics

The URI for searching the site is not done with a query, but with a path. `/search/query` is used instead of `?q=query`. How would I go about telling GA this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you found the solution, Not sure if this is a duplicate for [the SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687326/google-analytics-site-search-without-query-parameter-in-url-setup-jquery)

The solution to this is `fire a virtual pageview call` **only** on /search/ page

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/search?q='+<query-parameter>]);
```

**Recommendation** : Use Google Tag Manager for placing this code snippet, you can define a firing [rule based on url](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2644396?hl=en).

[Reference to the Google Help Section for search query parameter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en)